# bash replace part of text separated with marker that includes a keyword

Tags: regex, bash

I would like to replace everything between `:` if there's a keyword in it

Having

> TEXT="/Something/like-this:/How/can-one-replace/text/separated/with/colon/that-includes/a/**keyword**?:There/may-be/multiple/**keywords**:/Thanks:/**keyword**"

with:

```
sed -e 's/regex here that searches for keyword/\/some\/path/g' <<< $TEXT
```

To get:

> /Something/like-this:/some/path:/some/path:/Thanks:/some/path

P.S.
Another example to make it more clear: How can paths that includes `hello` be replaced with another path?

```
/opt/hello/bin:/bin:/home/user/hello:/home/user/bin:/media/hello 
=>
/some/path:/bin:/some/path:/home/user/bin:/some/path
```

My apologies for unclear question.

Comment: What do you mean by Replacement in the desired output?

Comment: You need to clarify your matching/replacement rule with more clarity.

Comment: 'Replacement' is path like string, i.e. /some/string

Comment: so, replacement should occur for the keyword. If the keyword is enclosed b/w `:`, then replace everything in between?

Comment: please explain your question a bit more clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this,

```
$ sed -r 's~^([^:]+):.*:([^:]+):(.*)$~\1:/Replacement:/Replacement:\2:/Replacement~g' file
/Something/like-this:/Replacement:/Replacement:/Thanks:/Replacement
```

Or something like this,

```
$ sed -r 's~^([^:]+):.*:([^:]+):(.*)$~\1:/*Replacement*:/*Replacement*:\2:/*Replacement*~g' file
/Something/like-this:/*Replacement*:/*Replacement*:/Thanks:/*Replacement*
```

Or

it may be like this, if you assign some path to Replacement variable,

```
$ Replacement=/foo/bar
$ sed -r "s~^([^:]+):.*:([^:]+):(.*)$~\1:/*$Replacement*:/*$Replacement*:\2:/*$Replacement*~g" file
/Something/like-this:/*/foo/bar*:/*/foo/bar*:/Thanks:/*/foo/bar*
```

Or

You may try this also,

```
awk -v RS=: -v var=/path -v ORS=: '{sub (/.*hello.*/,var)}1' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '/opt/hello/bin:/bin:/home/user/hello:/home/user/bin:/media/hello' | awk -v RS=: -v var=/foo/bar -v ORS=: '{sub (/.*hello.*/,var)}1'
/foo/bar:/bin:/foo/bar:/home/user/bin:/foo/bar:
```

**Explanation:**

- Awk inbuilt variable RS(Record seperator) and ORS(Output Record Seperator) are set to `:`. So awk breaks the string whenever it finds `:` in the input and treats the text after `:` would be in the next line.
- `ORS` is set to `:`, so awk prints the records with `:` as seperator.
- `-v var=/foo/bar` , Replacement string is assigned to a variable `var`.
- `sub (/.*hello.*/,var)`, if the record matches this regex, it replaces the whole record with the value in the variable `var`.
- `1`, to print all the records.

Comment: say we have `/opt/hello/bin:/bin:/home/user/hello:/home/user/bin:/media/hello`. How can I replace a path that includes `hello` with another path? (`hello` in this example is what I meant is a `keyword` in my question

Comment: But your desired output doesn't show about keyword? Please edit your question and add an example. Me or someone will surely help you.

Comment: now, it's clear. Add the above example to your question along with the desired output.

Comment: Added. Hopefully that would help. Thank you.

Comment: @ted something like this `echo '/opt/hello/bin:/bin:/home/user/hello:/home/user/bin:/media/hello' | awk -v RS=: -v var=/foo/bar -v ORS=: '{sub (/.*hello.*/,var)}1'`

Comment: nice, would be great if you make this your answer with some explanation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54357/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-ted).

Comment: If we want to remove the last colon then fed the whole command to this `sed 's/:$/$/g'` command

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
sed 's/:/::/g;s/^/:/;s/$/:/;s/:[^:]*keyword[^:]*:/:REPLACEMENT:/g;s/^://;s/:$//;s/::/:/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash

```
IFS=: read -ra arr <<<'/opt/hello/bin:/bin:/home/user/hello:/home/user/bin:/media/hello'
v=$(IFS=:; printf "%s\n" "${arr[*]/*hello*/\/some\/path}")
echo $v
/some/path:/bin:/some/path:/home/user/bin:/some/path
```